# Is it possible to set a maximum value for a number field in Firestore?

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I want to increment a field saved in Firestore, but it should not exceed a certain value. 
Is it possible to set a maximum value for a field?

If not, what's the preferred way to implement such a limit in Kotlin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking about `FieldValue.increment()`, it's not possible.  You should instead use a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) to read the document, compute a new value within appropriate limits, then write it back to the document.

If you're asking if it's possible to reject bad values altogether, no matter how they got written, you can do that with [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started), assuming that the write is coming from a web or mobile client.  Backend code bypasses security rules.

Comment: I agree with this answer as per this [documentation](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/03/increment-server-side-cloud-firestore.html)

Comment: Agreed on your answer Doug, although I'd probably frame it as "Yes, this is possible. To enforce a maximum value on a field, you can implement this in security rules with something like `allow write: if request.resource.data().number_field <= 10000`". :)