# Update counter in a Firestore document with GCF/pubsub

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I have clients who publish messages on a PubSub, and a GCF triggered each message received, which edit a document in my firestore. The document has an id, name of a room, and the current number of people inside this room. The GCF increases the current number.

But I think that if there are two messages for the same room at the same time, the gcf won't do the right job and i won't have the final +2 on my document ?

Basically, the GCF gets the document, and increases the current number.

How could I do to handle the multiple messages arriving at the same time for the same room ?

Comment: The "same time" isn't clear. You want a time window in which you want to deduplicate the same message. is it what you need?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Not really, I admit that two clients will enter the same room and click the button at "the same time". Two messages arrive in the PubSub and two GCF are triggered. They get the same document, and add +1 at this document. I have only +1 in my document, but I should have +2 .

Comment: Ok, you want +2; not +1, so not deduplication. understood. Did you try transaction with Firestore? Anyway, how many messages per second do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [`FieldValue.increment()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#static-increment) you can be sure that the field will be incremented correctly. As explained in this Firebase blog [article](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/03/increment-server-side-cloud-firestore.html), "with `FieldValue.increment()`, the database would instantly make the change based on whatever value it has".

In a Cloud Function for Firebase, do as follows:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const FieldValue = require('firebase-admin').firestore.FieldValue;


exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('...').onRun(async (context) => {
  // ...
  await admin.firestore().collection("...").doc("...").update({ nbrOfPeople: FieldValue.increment(1) });
  // ...
  return null;
});
```

Comment: Thank you that's Exactly what I was looking for. Can it handle a max value ?

Comment: "Can it handle a max value" What do you exactly mean?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62459721/is-it-possible-to-set-a-maximum-value-for-a-number-field-in-firestore

Comment: @RenaudTarnec This is still subjected to 1 Write/Second limitation right? I mean while using increment also we need to make sure the document is not updated more than once per second right?

Comment: @Ayyappa yes you are right. In this case you should consider [distributed counters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters?hl=en)